# jquery Append add same value always

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I use this jQuery code to append a div to another:

```
$('#sklep').on('click', '.kup', function () {
    var cena = $('#cena').text();
    var tytul = $('#tytul').text();
    var iden = $('#id').text();
    var suma = $('#koszykdiv .cyfry').text();
    var dodawanie = parseInt(cena) + parseInt(suma);
    $('.cyfry').text(dodawanie);
    var source = $("#miniatura").attr("src");
    $('.koszyk_content_items').append($('<div class="item_koszyk"><div class="miniatura_koszyk"><img width="165" height="110" src="' + source + '"/></div><span     id="opis">' + tytul + ' - ' + cena + ' zł - </span><span class="identyfikator" style="display:none;">' + iden + '</span><a href="#" class="usun" id="delete">USUŃ</a></div>'));
    var licznik = $('#koszykdiv .licznik').text();
    alert(licznik);
    $('#identyfikator').text(licznik);
    var licznik_dodawanie = parseInt(licznik) + 1;
    $('#koszykdiv .licznik').text(licznik_dodawanie);
    $.cookie("obraz" + licznik_dodawanie, id);
    var cena = '';
    var tytul = '';
    var iden = '';
    var source = '';
});
```

but it always appends a div with the same variables values, even if parent of '.kup' href has another text values. Can you help me and tell where the problem is?

Comment: Do you have double IDs somewhere?

Comment: yes, this is example code where the '.kup' href is: http://pastebin.com/N35arLpe

Comment: There's no `#sklep` in that pastebin, and only one `.kup`.

Answer (score 0):

You say in your question that you get the same variable values "even if parent of '.kup' href has another text values."
This is because nothing in your code is relative to the '.kup'-element. You get the `src`-attribute of the element with `id=miniatura` everytime.